# how to remove the limit of results in rubys activeldap gem

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ldap

I have a LDAP Directory with 4000+ Users. But when i LdapUser.all() (LdapUser is my activeldap model derivated from ActiveLdap::Base) I only get 500 records back. Where/how can I remove this limit?

- Renato

Comment: It is quite possible that the service account you are using to bind to the directory server and retrieve results has a search limit imposed.  Do you get back any messages with your search results like **size limit exceeded**?

Comment: Meant to add - can you do the same search with the same service account using a different client (e.g. ldapsearch command line tool) and get back all 4k+?

Comment: Well i haven't managed to get ldapsearch running but when searching in Apache Directory Studio I get all the 4000+ entries back. But then again, it might be some Directory Studio magic that is doing that.

Comment: what directory server are you using?  Apache Directory Studio: nice full service functionality, but heavy on the resource use and hard to know what it does exactly. I would try this and make sure my account works the way I think it should... `ldapsearch -D "<fq dn of user>" -w <passsword> -h <host> -p port -s sub -b "<root of search>" "(objectclass=person)"` 500 seems awfully small for a client to impose on itself unless it is paging results or something - sorry I am unfamiliar with the product.

Comment: DOH! I had the wrong password so it connected anonymously... when login with the right credentials it works. Sorry for the time taken!